# Index 0 requested with size of 0

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to pull a record from the database but I am getting an error.

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

The following is the code I am using to pull the record.

```
public String[] getSingleTransaction(String table, String id) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        String[] data = new String[4];
        try{

            cursor = db.query(table, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_CREDIT, KEY_DEBIT, KEY_MEMO, KEY_TIMESTAMP}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                    new String[] {String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

            if(cursor != null) {

                cursor.moveToFirst();
                data[0] = cursor.getString(0); //This is where I am getting the error.
                data[1] = cursor.getString(1);
                data[2] = cursor.getString(2);
                data[3] = cursor.getString(3);
                data[4] = cursor.getString(4);
            }

            return data;
        }finally {

            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Is anyone able to see what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing i noticed is that you are accessing 5 elements..but your array was declared with 4. Your array must have **5 elements** **(size 5)**..so it will be declared like this:

```
String[] data = new String[5];
```

then before accessing the cursor, you have to check if it 'successfully' moved to the first position..with this:

```
boolean success = cursor.moveToFirst();
```

if it is 'TRUE' then you can access the cursor. In your case, it would return 'FALSE' if your query would lead to no results..EMPTY result.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if(cursor != null) {

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            data[0] = cursor.getString(0); //This is where I am getting the error.
            data[1] = cursor.getString(1);
            data[2] = cursor.getString(2);
            data[3] = cursor.getString(3);
            data[4] = cursor.getString(4);
        }
```

to this:

```
if(cursor != null) {
   if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            data[0] = cursor.getString(0); //This is where I am getting the error.
            data[1] = cursor.getString(1);
            data[2] = cursor.getString(2);
            data[3] = cursor.getString(3);
            data[4] = cursor.getString(4);
        }

     }
```

I think the problem is that your cursor is not null but is not returning values, that is why it crashes.

PD: You should increase your `String` array as the other answer says :) as the following:

`String[] data = new String[5];`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make sure that it contains the needed number of elements?

Comment: @Elenasys your answer is newer than mine, I have not copied from you, I do not need to.

Comment: @ChrisStratton you are right, I will change that, haven't noticed :)